# Get 'scores', 'labels' 'logits' and 'boxes' from model detr huggingface

Tags: conv-neural-network, object-detection, huggingface-transformers

We can apply this script to get objects prediction of an image:

```
from transformers import AutoImageProcessor, DetrForObjectDetection
import torch
from PIL import Image
import requests

url = "http://images.cocodataset.org/val2017/000000039769.jpg"
image = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)

image_processor = AutoImageProcessor.from_pretrained("facebook/detr-resnet-50")
model = DetrForObjectDetection.from_pretrained("facebook/detr-resnet-50")

inputs = image_processor(images=image, return_tensors="pt")
outputs = model(**inputs)
```

And the we can do like that to get 'scores', 'labels' and 'boxes':

```
results = image_processor.post_process_object_detection(outputs threshold=0.9)[0] 

# results: {'scores': tensor([0.9982, 0.9960, 0.9955, 0.9988, 0.9987], grad_fn=<IndexBackward0>),
# 'labels': tensor([75, 75, 63, 17, 17]),
# 'boxes': tensor([[ 6.2755e-02,  1.4752e-01,  2.7429e-01,  2.4580e-01],
#         [ 5.2069e-01,  1.5115e-01,  5.7551e-01,  3.9097e-01],
#         [-3.5316e-05,  2.3951e-03,  9.9957e-01,  9.8700e-01],
#         [ 2.0689e-02,  1.0845e-01,  4.9065e-01,  9.8110e-01],
#         [ 5.3969e-01,  4.9695e-02,  1.0006e+00,  7.6817e-01]],
#        grad_fn=<IndexBackward0>)}
```

How we can get 'scores', 'labels','boxes' and 'logits' and put them in the same dictionary for each image that ('threshold=0.9' for example)?

Access the logits:

```
logits = outputs.logits
```

Perform post-processing to obtain the desired fields:

```
results = processor.post_process_object_detection(outputs threshold=0.9)[0]
scores = results["scores"]
labels = results["labels"]
boxes = results["boxes"]
```

Combine the logits and the post-processed results into a single dictionary:

```
combined_results = {
    "logits": logits,
    "scores": scores,
    "labels": labels,
    "boxes": boxes
}
```

Comment: What is your question?